# Am I able to activate Windows 7 after support ends (either mainstream or extended support)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

OEM packages of Windows 7 Professional are still available at several online retailers.  My understanding is that such packages contain both physical media (disc) and an actiavtion code (printed on the disc, or wherever).  But I think that the operating system must be activated using the activation code, online or by phone, before it can be used.

As stated [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle), mainstream support for Windows 7 ended on **January 13, 2015** and extended support will end on **January 14, 2020**.

Suppose that today I purchase a OEM packages of Windows 7 Professional.

- Would I likely be able to activate Windows 7 today (June 2016)?
- Would I likely be able to activate Windows 7 after January 14, 2020, when extended support for Windows 7 ends?

Comment: Of course you will.  You can activate Windows XP today.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, XP will not outlive Windows 7.

On the other hand, Microsoft does have a new CEO, and has given away Windows 10 for the first year.  So who knows what business decisions they will make more than 3 years from now?  Until they announce anything definitive, all we can go by is speculation and reports of probably-not-binding statements that came directly from Microsoft.

I haven't heard anything about Windows 7 activation being turned off.  What I have heard is about Windows XP.

January 2014's article, [Windows XP End... More questions answered](http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-xp-end-of-support-in-april-three-more-questions-answered/) says, "Windows XP can still be installed and activated after end of support on April 8" ... "Computers running Windows XP will still work, they just won’t receive any new security updates."

[Will Microsoft Turn Off the Windows XP Activations Servers](http://www.windowsobserver.com/2013/09/17/will-microsoft-turn-off-the-windows-xp-activations-servers-after-official-support-ends-in-april-2014/) says, "After XP End Of Support, Windows XP will remain on MSDN and TechNet for customers who still need to activate and re-activate XP (there aren’t new retail copies). We don’t have a date to share around when activation will be shut off, but it will be on for the foreseeable future."

Let's not forget that Win9x/ME and XP both had their end of life pushed out later than originally announced.

(Your best bet, if you're really concerned, is to install Win7 now, upgrade to Win10 now, get the Win10 license, then re-install Win7 if you don't want Win10 now.  Chances seem good that if they do drop the ability to activate Win7 soon-ish, Win10 will still be activatable.)

So that's it.  To re-cap:

- Nothing definitive (regarding information available now) that I'm aware of, and there probably won't be anything definitive announced anytime soon
- If historical trends continue, it does seem probable that activation will still be available on January 15, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

I have had recently (May 2016) a need to activate Windows XP Professional and did this successfully via phone activation. My assumption would be if the usual way of activation (via the internet) fails you still be able to activate Windows 7 via phone.

You can find all the phone numbers Microsoft automated phone centers [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/existing-customer/activation-centers.aspx). This link states only for Volume Licensing but it also works fine retail.